# I need to find the average with the 3 parameters in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to print the people with average not greater than 4 for algebra.
For example, "SCHOOL: 131, NAME: BLA-BLA, AVERAGE: 3,5". Thats the thing i've tried but it gave me an exception "sequence contains no elements"
upd: "not greater than 4"

```
var result = students
                .OrderBy(s => s.Surname)
                .ThenBy(o => o.Initials)
                .Select(n => new
                {
                    Name = n.Surname + " " + n.Initials,
                    Class = n.Class,
                    Average = students
                        .Where(s => s.Subject == "Algebra" && n.Surname == s.Surname && n.Initials == s.Initials)
                        .Average(w => w.Mark)
                });

var students = new[]
            {
                new {Subject = "Algebra", Surname = "Jopin", Initials = "S.S", Class = 5, Mark = 2},
                new {Subject = "Algebra", Surname = "Jopin", Initials = "S.S", Class = 5, Mark = 2},
                new {Subject = "Algebra", Surname = "Jopin", Initials = "S.S", Class = 5, Mark = 3},
                new {Subject = "Geometry", Surname = "Jopin", Initials = "S.S", Class = 5, Mark = 5},
                new {Subject = "C.S", Surname = "Jopin", Initials = "S.S", Class = 5, Mark = 5},
                new {Subject = "C.S", Surname = "Jopin", Initials = "S.S", Class = 5, Mark = 5},
                new {Subject = "Algebra", Surname = "Bloom", Initials = "Q.V", Class = 2, Mark = 5},
                new {Subject = "Algebra", Surname = "Bloom", Initials = "Q.V", Class = 2, Mark = 5},
                new {Subject = "Algebra", Surname = "Bloom", Initials = "Q.V", Class = 2, Mark = 5},
                new {Subject = "Geometry", Surname = "Bloom", Initials = "Q.V", Class = 2, Mark = 5},
                new {Subject = "C.S", Surname = "Bloom", Initials = "Q.V", Class = 2, Mark = 5},
                new {Subject = "C.S", Surname = "Bloom", Initials = "Q.V", Class = 2, Mark = 5},
                new {Subject = "Geometry", Surname = "Roflov", Initials = "E.Y", Class = 1, Mark = 2},
                new {Subject = "C.S", Surname = "Roflov", Initials = "E.Y", Class = 1, Mark = 2},
                new {Subject = "C.S", Surname = "Roflov", Initials = "E.Y", Class = 1, Mark = 2},
                new {Subject = "Algebra", Surname = "Einstein", Initials = "B.H", Class = 4, Mark = 3},
                new {Subject = "Algebra", Surname = "Einstein", Initials = "B.H", Class = 4, Mark = 4},
                new {Subject = "Geometry", Surname = "Einstein", Initials = "B.H", Class = 4, Mark = 5}
            };
```

Comment: Hi, your error does not reflect your code. Please [edit] your question, (use this link: [edit]) and past the code that's causing the error.

Comment: Hi, the exception happens because Roflov doesn't have any Algebra records. I believe it's better to use GroupBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Average method can fail with InvalidOperationException if the sequence contains no elements.
From your example, it looks like at least for student "Roflow E.Y" there is no entry for "Algebra"

Something like this should do what you want.

```
var result = students
    .Where(s => s.Subject == "Algebra")
    .GroupBy(s => new{s.Surname, s.Initials, s.Class})
    .Select(g => new{ Name = g.Key.Surname + g.Key.Initials, g.Key.Class, Average = g.Average(x => x.Mark)})
    .Where(x => x.Average >= 4)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```